# Magento 2 Add to Cart Submit Button Value

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I have added **custom add to cart** submit button on **product detail page**.

On submit, i am getting other form fields values but **not getting** submit button name and value.

So how can i get the name or value of submit button in post.

Does anyone know how to solve it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please put your custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Override Js file in your theme and update the code that you want to update:

vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js

To

app/design/frontend/ThemeName/PackageName/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js

Comment: Thanks for your response but i don't want to do with theme, I will override in module and try.

Comment: You can override with the custom module as below: 
In your app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js 
Add the following code.
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
         'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart':'Custom_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cart',
         catalogAddToCart:'Custom_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
        }
    }
};

Put your add to cart file in app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\web\js path with name catalog-add-to-cart.js
copy and past the parent file and Make your changes.
Hope this will help.